# Proof Regarding Indexed Sets and Functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $I,J$ are sets and $\{A_{i,j}: (i,j) \in I \times J\}$ is an indexed set, then

$$ \cap_{i \in I} \left( \cup_{j \in J} A_{i,j} \right) = \cup_{f \in F} \left( \cap_{i \in I} A_{i,f(i)} \right)$$ where $F$ is the set of all functions from $I$ to $J$.

I was given this problem in my Topology course. Although we are using the textbook *Principles of Topology* by Fred H. Croom, this assignment is not found on any page. Because I notice that one side starts with an intersection followed by a union and the other side is reversed, my intuition is telling me that De Morgan's Laws would apply here somewhere.

I know that two sets are equal if they are subsets of each other, but how does one go about showing this with what is given? As always, any assistance is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just by ‘chasing elements’. Suppose first that $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}A_{i,j}$. Then for each $i\in I$ we have $x\in \bigcup_{j\in J}A_{i,j}$, so there must be at least one $g(i)\in J$ such that $x\in A_{i,g(i)}$. Clearly $g$ is a function from $I$ to $J$, so $g\in F$. And we’ve chosen $g$ in such a way that $x\in A_{i,g(i)}$ for each $i\in I$, so $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,g(i)}$. Thus,

$$x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,g(i)}\subseteq\bigcup_{f\in F}\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,f(i)}\;,$$

and it follows that

$$\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}A_{i,j}\subseteq\bigcup_{f\in F}\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,f(i)}\;.$$

The other direction is quite similar. If $x\in\bigcup_{f\in F}\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,f(i)}\;$, then there is an $f\in F$ such that $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,f(i)}$. But then $x\in A_{i,f(i)}\subseteq\bigcup_{j\in J}A_{i,j}$ for each $i\in I$, so

$$x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}A_{i,j}\;,$$

and

$$\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}A_{i,j}\supseteq\bigcup_{f\in F}\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,f(i)}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a tacitly underlying "ground set" $C$ of "colors", and we are given a function
$$A: \quad I\times J\to {\cal P}(C),\qquad (i,j)\mapsto A_{i,j}$$
defining a matrix $\bigl[A_{i,j}\bigr]$ whose entries are subsets of $C$, i.e., sets of colors.

For given $i\in I$ the expression $\bigcup_{j\in J} A_{i,j}$ denotes the set of all colors occurring somewhere in the $i^{\,\rm th}$ row of this matrix, and $$C_*:=\bigcap_{i\in I}\left(\bigcup_{j\in J} A_{i,j}\right)$$ denotes the set  of colors occurring in *every* row.

When $c\in C_*$ then for each $i\in I$ there is a $j\in J$ with $c\in A_{i,j}$. Choosing such a $j$ for every $i\in I$ defines an $f:\>I\to J$, and we then have
$$c\in \bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i,f(i)}\ .$$
This proves $$c\in C^*:=\bigcup_{f\in F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i,f(i)}\right)\ .$$

Conversely, if $c\in C^*$ then $c\in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i,f(i)}$ for some $f\in I$. This implies that $c$ occurs in *every* row of our matrix; whence $c\in C_*$.